# While loop always being executed once but works correctly on the second time. Help? [c++]

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with a while loop in c++. The while loop is always being executed the first time around but when the program reaches the cin of the while loop the while loop works perfectly I was wondering what I was doing wrong. Thanks in advance. Also I am sorry if the problem is noobish. I am still a beginner.

```
cout<<"Would you like some ketchup? y/n"<<endl<<endl<<endl; //Ketchup
selection screen
cin>>optketchup;



while (optketchup != "yes" && optketchup != "no" && optketchup != "YES" && optketchup != "Yes"  && optketchup != "YEs"  && optketchup != "yEs"  && optketchup != "YeS"
     && optketchup != "yeS" &&  optketchup != "YeS"  && optketchup != "yES" && optketchup != "y"  && optketchup != "Y"  && optketchup != "No"  && optketchup != "nO"
      && optketchup != "NO"  && optketchup != "n"  && optketchup != "No");
{

    cout<<"You have entered an entered "<<optketchup<<" which is an invalid
 option. Please try again."<<endl;
    cin>>optketchup;

}


if (optketchup == "yes" || optketchup == "YES" || optketchup == "Yes"  || optketchup == "YEs"  || optketchup == "yEs"  || optketchup == "YeS"
     || optketchup == "yeS" ||  optketchup == "YeS"  || optketchup == "yES" || optketchup == "y"  || optketchup == "Y")
{
    slcketchup == "with";
}
else
{
    slcketchup == "without";
}

cout<<"Your sandwich shall be "<<slcketchup<<" ketchup."<<endl;



system ("pause");
```

Again thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is `optketchup`? Also, you need one equals sign to assign a value, and the homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: Simply converting your string to either lowercase or uppercase and testing against just "yes" or "YES" and "no" or "NO" would be a lot more sane than testing every single combination of upper/lowercase letters.

Comment: Not just that he is testing for each & every uppercase/lowercase combination, not once, but twice. He is going to be so tired after all this testing that he will be needing that sandwich.

Comment: There is no need to show the full code: The code you shown is enough, and it is independent from other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon(';') in the `while`. That's causing the problem.

Don't write

```
while(.... lots of conditions ...);
{
    //stuff
}
```

Write

```
while(.... lots of conditions ...)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Notice the lack of the `;` in the 2nd one.

Other than that, what if you had to check for the word `Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`. How many combinations of upper & lower cases would you end up checking?
Instead, convert the input into upper case & compare against upper case `YES` or `NO` or `PNEUMONOULTRAMICROSCOPICSILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS`.

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much. I must have put it there by mistake. Thank you so much it works now! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

A control statement executing a single line of code can be written in two different way.

```
if (optketchup == "yes") {
  slcketchup = "with";
}
```

```
if (optketchup == "yes") slcketchup = "with";
```

Also the following code is valid; the difference is that there isn't any instruction to execute when `optketchup` is equal to `"yes"`.

```
if (optketchup == "yes");
```

This is true for other control statements, such as your `while`.

Also, `=` is the assignment operator, while `==` is the comparison operator. You are using the latter when you wanted to use the first.
Then, as others already pointed out, just convert `optketchup` to lowercase: You will just need to compare the lowercase value with `"yes"`, instead of checking any possible variant of "yes" written using a mix of lowercase/uppercase characters.

Comment: Thank you! The == and = problem was also screwing things up. But the main error was solved by user93353 but still thank you very much! :D